# многостраничный сайт, как правильно организовать?

Tags: javascript, html, css, архитектура

Делаю многостраничный сайт. `Footer` и `Header` (по советам из сети), думаю сделать в отдельном файле(шаблон) и при загрузке страницы подгружать(через `js`).

Есть вопросы по поводу `.sass` файлов, получается мне придется 
делать отдельный `syle.sass` и `media.sass` файлы для каждой внутренней страницы?

Я новичок в `webe`, есть неплохой опыт в верстке `LP`, многостраничный делаю впервые.

Как все это грамотно организовать?
Гуглил, почти везде описываются какие-то частные случаи. 
Буду рад любой ссылке или совету)

**P.S Во внутренних страницах наблюдается такая странность: при клике на любую ссылку происходит переход на `index.html`. Как исправить?(пользуюсь`gulp`)**

Comment: Зачем код? я спрашиваю как правильно организовать проект

Comment: Что значит на чистом JS? Многостраничный сайт можно сделать и на чистои HTML, о чем речь? Да и зачем подгружать страницы, они так много весят что нельзя сразу всех загрузить?

Comment: заголовок исправил. Я спрашиваю как правильно организовать сайт. Footer и header хочу сделать как шаблон, и чтобы по сто раз не писать - добавлять этот код при переходе на внутреннюю страницу. На самом деле, я не знаю как организовать и поэтому спрашиваю, как будет лучше

Comment: Лучше используйте MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переношу/перевожу ответ с [англоязычного SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513635/7387243).

По сути вы просто хотите подключать модули в виде обычных HTML конструкций, которые будут серией div а так же ID или CSS файлы, установите каждому display: none. Потом используйте jQuery .show() и .hide() что бы показыть или скрыть их.

Что бы быть точнее вы хотите организовать навигацию примерно так:

```
$("#my-home-nav").click(function(){
    $("#my-home-div").show(); // or .fadeIn(), etc.
    $("#my-about-div").hide();
    $("#my-contact-div").hide();
});
```

Этот код может быть крайне неудобным если страниц будет очень много. Следующий код может упростить задачу:

```
var pageNames = ["home", "about", "contact"];
var namespace = "my";

var pages = pageNames.map(function(pageName) {
    return {
        nav: pageNameSelector(pageName, "nav"),
        div: pageNameSelector(pageName, "div")
    };
});

pages.forEach(function(page) {
    page.nav.click(function() {
        clearPages(pages);
        page.div.show();
    });
});

function pageNameSelector(pageName, type) {
    return $(["#" + namespace, pageName, type].join("-"));
}

function clearPages(pages) {
    pages.forEach(function(page) {
        page.div.hide();
    });
}
```

Теперь все что нужно делать это следовать данной структуре, где id для nav/div даны в виде `NAMESPACE-PAGENAME-TYPE` и когда вы добавляете дополнительные страницы в `pageNames` функциональность показать/скрыть будет работать без пробелем.

Или можно просто использовать [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) или что-то подобное.

(C) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513528/how-do-i-create-a-website-with-multiple-pages-that-the-user-can-access-without-r

Comment: P.S Во внутренних страницах наблюдается такая странность: при клике на любую ссылку происходит переход на index.html. Как исправить?(пользуюсь gulp)

Есть идеи как это можно исправить?

Comment: @codecaramel Я не знаю что у вас там, нужно видеть код.

Comment: файл index.html :
есть ссылка которая переводит на внутреннюю страницу:
<a href= "brand.html"> Brands<a>

При переходе на brand.html:
Любая ссылка на странице <a href="#">whatever<a>
При клике на эту "любую ссылку" происходит переход на index.html.

Comment: @codecaramel вы хоть видели что вы написали? Я ничего не понял. Но наверное нужно видеть фрагмент html/js кода, при чем не в комментариях а дополняйте в ответ. Тут только я сижу пытаюсь понять что вам нужно, до сих пор никто не видел кода что бы вам помочь.

Comment: https://codepen.io/codecaramel/pen/qoaZRp

закинул туда код navigation menu, который находится в header и дублируется во всех внутренних страницах.

Когда нажимаю на одну из этих ссылок во внутренних страницах,(неважно на какую) всегда перекидывает на главную.

Та же ситуация со всеми остальными ссылкаами на всех внутренних страницах, при нажатии переводит на домашнюю.

Comment: @codecaramel и в чем проблема, все работает правильно.